# Exercise soon after waking up vs during the day vs before bed

Tags: exercise, routine, time

Does the time of day when one exercises make a difference?

I understand that consistency and other things are all more important, but given a choice (due to WFH situations) how does one choose when to exercise?

Comment: I’ve proposed a duplicate for this question, though it is specific to resistance training. If that is what you are asking about, then I think it’s a good dupe target, but if your question is really about cardiorespiratory training, it probably isn’t a suitable dupe. Either, you should be more specific about what sort of exercise you are asking about and what outcomes you are trying to optimize for.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yes, I wanted to ask in the context of muscle growth etc. The question you linked to is a reasonable duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

My experience from Running

Early in the morning - you need to make sure you are properly warmed up, if I climb out of bed and put on my running shoes and run out the front door I have noticed that I can get really injured and I also run poorly. I now warm up and then I will also walk the first 500m to 1Km just to give my legs a chance. If you take a lot of exercise then you may be tired for the rest of the day and work can be a struggle. I do a lot of my longer runs in the morning albeit at the weekend and as long as I am properly warmed up I dont notice any difference in performance to running at other times of the day.

Middle of the day - if you are WFH and live in a part of the world that has short days in the winter then a lunch run can be a good option (and safer option depending where you live). Maybe you arrange with work that you have a longer lunch break but work a bit earlier/later. (or hope they dont notice ;))

End of the day - this is when I do most of my running. Positives are I dont have to finish running at a certain time to be at work. My body is also fairly stretched from a day walking around. Downside is I can be tired at the end of the day and the TV wins over exercise.